# Unable to upload shapefile using geoserver REST API and php

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, php

I am not able to upload shapefile and create a store in Geoserver using its rest api and Php. below is my php code

```
 <?php
  // Open log file
$logfh = fopen("GeoserverPHP.log", 'w') or die("can't open log file");

// Initiate cURL session
$service = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/"; 
$request = "workspaces/robin/datastores/nepalds/file.shp"; 

$url = $service . $request ; 
$ch = curl_init($url);

// Optional settings for debugging
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $logfh); 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); 

 $passwordStr = "admin:geoserver"; 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $passwordStr);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD,true); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,true);
//POST data
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: 
application/zip"));

//POST return code
    //Required POST request settings
  $post = array(
"file" => "@" .realpath("nepal_shp.zip")
 );

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$successCode = 201; 

$buffer = curl_exec($ch); 


$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
if ($info['http_code'] != $successCode) {
  $msgStr = "# Unsuccessful cURL request to ";
  $msgStr .= $url." [". $info['http_code']. "]\n";
  fwrite($logfh, $msgStr);
} else {
  $msgStr = "# Successful cURL request to ".$url."\n";
  fwrite($logfh, $msgStr);
}
fwrite($logfh, $buffer."\n");

curl_close($ch); 
fclose($logfh);  // close logfile

echo '<a href="http://localhost/user.html">Click here to check </a>';
?>
```

It's been more than a week i am trying to create a store but am not able to. I know where the actual problem is actually residing on, probably associated with wrong directory upload ie. it can't actually find a path and upload the shapefile.

```
     ERROR MSG:(multiple)
    13 Jul 15:42:30 INFO [rest.catalog] - Auto-configuring datastore: 
    nepaldss
13 Jul 15:42:30 WARN [shapefile.shp] - Could not open the .shx file, 
  continuing assuming the .shp file is not sparse
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  c:\tomcat\webapps\geoserver\data\data\robin\nepaldss\nepaldss.shx (The 
   system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at 


    org.geotools.data.shapefile.files.ShpFiles.getReadChannel 
    (ShpFiles.java:758)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile.<init>(IndexFile.java:72)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.<init>( 
   ShapefileReader.java:267)
    at 


  org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileSetManager.openShapeReader 
   (ShapefileSetManager.java:48)
    at 

  org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureSource.readAttributes 
(ShapefileFeatureSource.java:520)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureSource.buildFeatureType 
(ShapefileFeatureSource.java:479)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema 
(ContentFeatureSource.java:328)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema 
 (ContentFeatureSource.java:297)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema 
 (ContentFeatureSource.java:106)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildFeatureType(CatalogBuilder.java:394)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.DataStoreFileController.dataStorePut(DataStoreFileController.java:454)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor265.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:458)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1139)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
     13 Jul 14:06:42 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - 
    java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at 
    org.geoserver.rest.catalog.DataStoreFileController.dataStorePut 
    (DataStoreFileController.java:510)
```

I am totally new in this  field. What possible changes would i need to make to my code.

Comment: what is in nepal_shp.zip?

Comment: hi @IanTurton sir. It consists  .shp, .shx , .prj files.

Comment: there should almost certainly be a .dbf file too 0 ideally we need to see the rest of the line in the log `c:\tomcat\webapps\geoserver\data\data\kaylin\.....`

Comment: there are .dbf and .snb files too. @IanTurton sir, i have posted the rest of the log lines as well

Comment: does `c:\tomcat\webapps\geoserver\data\data\robin\nepaldss\nepaldss.shx` exist?

Comment: actually no @IanTurton sir . nepal_shp.zip, which  is in the data directory of the geoserver, has all the necessary .shx files. i dont know why and how it created nepaldss.shx,because i have .shx files like-(nepal.shx,nepal_zones.shx etc) nepaldss is just a store name i gave

Comment: the expectation is (I think) that the name of the shapefile is the same as the zip file.

Comment: no @IanTurton sir, actually the problem is that the zip file should have been unzipped into c:\tomcat\webapps\geoserver\data\data\robin\nepaldss\[.....]
but it has been searching for nepaldss.shx instead of unzipping all the files into the directory